# How to decode a string that has been UTF-8 encoded twice to simple UTF-8?

Tags: c#, mysql, utf-8

I have a huge MySQL table which has its rows encoded in UTF-8 twice.
For example "Újratárgyalja" is stored as "ÃšjratÃ¡rgyalja".

The MySQL .Net connector downloads them this way. I tried lots of combinations with `System.Text.Encoding.Convert()` but none of them worked.

Sending `set names 'utf8'` (or other charset) won't solve it.

How can I decode them from double UTF-8 to UTF-8?

Comment: I have to upvote this question, mainly because it prompted Alex's answer, which is pretty damn nifty.  Also, encoding can be a tricky business in general, as I rediscovered just experimenting with Alex's answer on my own machine.  I have the feeling his approach might help (at least as a clue) in other interoperability contexts as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Peculiar problem, but I think I can reproduce it by a suitably-unholy mix of UTF-8 and Latin-1 (not by just two uses of UTF-8 without an interspersed mis-step in Latin-1 though). Here's the whole weird round trip, "there and back again" (Python 2.* or IronPython should both be able to reproduce this):

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
uni = u'Újratárgyalja'
enc1 = uni.encode('utf-8')
enc2 = enc1.decode('latin-1').encode('utf-8')
dec3 = enc2.decode('utf-8')
dec4 = dec3.encode('latin-1').decode('utf-8')

for x in (uni, enc1, enc2, dec3, dec4):
  print repr(x), x
```

This is the interesting output...:

```
u'\xdajrat\xe1rgyalja' Újratárgyalja
'\xc3\x9ajrat\xc3\xa1rgyalja' Újratárgyalja
'\xc3\x83\xc2\x9ajrat\xc3\x83\xc2\xa1rgyalja' ÃjratÃ¡rgyalja
u'\xc3\x9ajrat\xc3\xa1rgyalja' ÃjratÃ¡rgyalja
u'\xdajrat\xe1rgyalja' Újratárgyalja
```

The weird string starting with `Ã` appears as enc2, i.e. two utf-8 encodings WITH an interspersed latin-1 decoding thrown into the mix. And as you can see it can be undone by the exactly-converse sequence of operations: decode as utf-8, re-encode as latin-1, re-decode as utf-8 again -- and the original string is back (yay!).

I believe that the normal round-trip properties of both Latin-1 (aka ISO-8859-1) and UTF-8 should guarantee that this sequence will work (sorry, no C# around to try in that language right now, but I would expect that the encoding/decoding sequences should not depend on the specific programming language in use).

Comment: Ingenious.  And the answer is accepted.  For my own curiosity though, I tried reproducing your results on Windows with Python 2.6.1.  Had a tough time of it, because the very act of copying and pasting your code created issues (for example, pasting into Notepad and the IDLE editor were quite different!).  Then executing it created more issues (had to resort to printing only repr(x) if outside of IDLE).  [I know, I know, get a Real Operating System, etc.]

Answer (score 1):

When you write "The MySQL .Net connector downloads them this way." there's a good chance this means the MySQL .Net connector believes it is speaking Latin-1 to MySQL, while MySQL believes the conversation is in UTF-8. There's also a chance the column is declared as Latin-1, but actually contains UTF-8 data.

If it's the latter (column labelled Latin-1 but data is actually UTF-8) you will get mysterious collation problems and other bugs if you make use of MySQL's text processing functions, ORDER BY on the column, or other situations where the text "means something" rather than just being bytes sent over the wire.

In either case you should try to fix the underlying problem, not least because it is going to be a complete headache for whoever has to maintain the system otherwise.

Comment: The column is declared as UTF-8 and the data stored in it is also UTF-8, but for some mysterious reasons the PHP's PDO extension encoded it twice.

Comment: You never mentioned anything about PHP before. So is the data actually corrupt in the MySQL DB?

Comment: I mentioned it right in the first sentence, that it is stored in the MySQL database that way. However, I didn't mention that PHP's PDO extension stored them this way, because the original question was how to decode a string in C# that has been UTF-8 encoded twice.

Comment: OK, so in this case you definitely ought to fix it in the database, for all the reasons I gave in the second paragraph.

It is annoyingly easy to misconfigure PHP + MySQL and do this, I've done it myself, but fortunately I caught it pretty quickly. You can do the same decode / encode run around inside MySQL, but you need to be careful (create a backup first).

Answer (score -1):

You could try using

```
SELECT CONVERT(`your_column` USING ascii)
FROM `your_table`
```

at the MySQL query level.  This is a stab in the dark, though.